# Can't log in to Ubuntu 16.10 on VMware

Tags: login, vmware, 16.10, vmware-player

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10. I'm using it on VMware Player on a Windows 10 host. After rebooting to finish installation, I am unable to login. I entered my password and hit Enter and then it locked up. I can't do anything and the mouse doesn't show up.

Comment: Anyone? I might have to reinstall 16.04 and then not upgrade to 16.10. I tried rebooting the VM many times but it freezes and doesn't work. Please respond. Thanks

Comment: I encountered the same issue, this http://askubuntu.com/a/841283/617150 worked for me